# Swift offset(of:) for UInt8 has 2 byte offset

Tags: swift

Why does a variable UInt8 in a swift struct show an offset of 2? However a struct of just UInt8s shows an offset of 1?

```
struct Test {
    let a: UInt8
    let b: UInt16
}

MemoryLayout<Test>.offset(of: \Test.a) // 0
MemoryLayout<Test>.offset(of: \Test.b) // 2 (not 1)

struct Test2 {
    let a: UInt8
    let b: UInt8
    let c: UInt8
}

MemoryLayout<Test2>.offset(of: \Test2.a) // 0
MemoryLayout<Test2>.offset(of: \Test2.b) // 1
MemoryLayout<Test2>.offset(of: \Test2.c) // 2
```

Comment: `b` is an `UInt16` and that is aligned to an even address. Details at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how Swift aligns your properties in memory. For your first struct, the `alignment` is 2, whereas your second struct has an alignment of 1.

Your properties in `Test` are not stored in memory all packed together like this:

```
x y y
```

where `x` represents a byte for `a`, and `y` represents a byte for `b`.

It looks more like this:

```
x   y y
```

Notice the padding after `x`.

The point I am trying to make here is that Swift divides up a part of memory into "slices" to put the properties of your structs in. These equal slices has to be able to contain all your properties. This is why in `Test`, the memory has to be cut up into slices of 2 bytes, to fit in a `UInt16`.

In `Test2` however, cutting up the memory into slices of 1 byte is enough to contain `UInt8`s.

This "How many bytes per slice" number is the `alignment`.

For why Swift cuts memory up this way, read [this](https://swiftunboxed.com/internals/size-stride-alignment/).

Comment: That “equal slices” part might be misleading.  A `struct { a: UInt8; b: UInt8; c: UInt16 }` is not divided into three equal slices of 2 bytes.

Comment: @MartinR Edited.