# How do I cast a memory buffer to a swift struct

Tags: swift

In C I am able to cast a memory buffer as a struct. This makes parsing extremely easy. How can I do the same in swift?

I have tried utilizing `offset(of: ...)` but it doesn't seem to pack the size into the shortest possible size, and I am unaware of a directive that informs swift to pack the memory.

I asked the question of `offset(of: ...)` here: [Swift offset(of:) for UInt8 has 2 byte offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638891/swift-offsetof-for-uint8-has-2-byte-offset)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525922/reading-data-into-a-struct-in-swift

Comment: Btw, *both* C and Swift align struct members, and just copying a C struct into a memory buffer does not “pack” the elements either.

Comment: @MartinR I've marked my C structs as packed, but this attribute isn't available in Swift.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302927/1187415: *"If you depend on a specific layout, you should define the struct in C and import it into Swift for now."* Even the layout of packed C structures is preserved in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR Great! Thanks.